# architecture guidance for multiple messages in an array

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

We are building a simple pub-sub system using Kafka. The publisher is a service that receives an array of messages (called a Block) from a client app that is published to Kafka topic. We have 4 partitions and 4 instances of a subscriber handling these.
The Block (array) can have a limit of 10 messages currently (business constraints) but could go up to 25 in the future.
Will it be better to write each message in the Block individually, or put the entire Block at once as one Kafka event.

Our take is to do one block at once so that one consumer instance can process all messages. The other consumer instances can be processing other Blocks that the Publisher is receiving.
Is there any guidance/recommended practices around such use cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka stores bytes. There's no best practice here "for Kafka", so it ultimately is up to your processing requirements. For example, if you did write individual messages for one block, your consumer then needs a way to discover the start/end/"order of data" for "each block". In an array, it's only "one record".

Keep in mind that Kafka has a default record size limit, so large serialized arrays should be split if not overriding the default settings. But, if you serialize data in compact binary formats like Protobuf or Avro, it'll occupy less space

Comment: This makes sense. Researched a bit further on Kafka Parallel Consumer. If we

Comment: I've not used that, but I think it only starts parallel threads within the JVM per partition, not handles splitting arrays into single records... Kafka Streams flatMap processor can be used for that